# exit status code for shell script execution

Tags: shell

I am trying to run a shell script(A) from another shell script(B). For testing purpose, the shell script(A) will always throw exception/error (just for testing). I am trying to get the exit status code immediately after running that script.

code:

case 1:

```
errormsg=$(sample.sh 2>&1)
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
echo $?
echo "Successful."
else
echo $?
echo "Error."
```

output:

```
0
Successful
```

case 2 :

```
errormsg=$(sample.sh 2>&1)
echo $?
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
echo $?
echo "Successful."
else
echo $?
echo "Error."
```

output:

```
1
1
Error
```

Why there is difference in output? Shouldn't the output be 'Error' in the case 1 too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$?` always give the result of the last executed command.

In case 1 this is your external script, but in case 2 it is the `echo $?`

That's why you get different results

Comment: Found the solution. Thanks anyway.